How to make custom error message on Laravel Precognition?
Its simply question, when i trying to make validation method on laravel, i can use like
$rules = [
  'username' => 'required,unique:Userlogin,username',
  'password' => 'required',
  'email'    => 'required,unique:Userlogin,email'
];

$messages = [
  'required'  => 'The :attribute field is required.',
  'unique'    => ':attribute is already used'
];

$request->validate($rules,$messages);

But how can i make custom error message on laravel precognition?

Shouldn't the syntax be $messages = ['username.required' => ..., 'password.required' => ..., 'username.unique' => ..., 'email.unique' => ...];?

What does your existing codes outputs? Doesn't it work?
